# Load report Failed error. Download not working

Tags: crystal-reports

Hi I am trying to download a Crystal Report, but it gives an error like below:

```
Load report failed.    
ReportDocument crReportGuj = new ReportDocument();
                crReportGuj.Load(mappedPath"\\Reports\\Gujarathi\\ObjectionRegionalNotice.rpt");
```

Comment: ReportDocument crReportGuj = new ReportDocument();
        crReportGuj.Load(mappedPath+"\\Reports\\Gujarathi\\ObjectionRegionalNotice.rpt");

Comment: Seems like a you need a course in both Crystal Report and StackOver flow